# Buying pork for someone

Tags: sadaqah, pork

Salam alaikum, I had a question in regards to pork. Awhile ago I came across a homeless woman and I told her since I don’t give homeless people money I can buy her food instead and as it were we were standing next to a Lidl. I told her she can pick out couple of items and she picked up chicken, potatoes and other items. She also picked up ham and at that time my brain did register that it was haram but I was preoccupied and it didn’t occur to me that I shouldn’t be paying for pork. I think my brain would’ve alerted me to any alcohol but it just dismissed the chicken and ham until I was thinking about it afterwards. So my question is did I bring sin upon myself whilst I was trying to do an act of charity. Would that act even count? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You still did a good deed.

- You have supported someone in need
- You tried to care for that your gift will be used for good.
- You didn't choose the ham, so you didn't intend to give something haram. You are not responsible for her choice.